# PHP preg_match special characters only

Tags: php, preg-match

I try to find a preg_match that filters strings that contain **only** special characters like **-**.

However, the string itself can contain special characters but it should not be special characters only.

Any ideas how to do that?

Result should return true if string only contains special characters. So something like

```
if(preg_match('//',$string)) echo $string; //I leave the pattern empty as this is the actual question.
```

Comment: Please show expected output and what result you are getting right now + code

Comment: Can't help much with code as I'm looking for the matching pattern. I do know how to find special chars in string but I do need it to filter strings that only contain special chars like ------

Comment: Please, give some test cases. Input strings and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the string for any alphanumeric character.

```
$one=  "%^&";
$two = "asd%asd";


function notOnlySpecialChars($str) {
    if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9]/', $str)) { //Replaced _ with -
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
notOnlySpecialChars($one); //false
notOnlySpecialChars($two); //true
```